# Web page button click in UIWebView works on Simulate not on iOS device

Tags: html, ios, uitableview, uiwebview

I have what appears to be an interesting problem.  I have a UITableView where one of the table view cells contains a UIWebView.  In the UIWebView I place some HTML code.  On the simulator I can click on the webpage buttons and the page reacts correctly to the click.  But when I run the program on the device, the buttons stop reacting as they should.

Everything is fairly straight forward and simple.  I have a UITableViewCell that holds a UIWebView.  When the UITableViewCell is loaded the UIWebView receives the HTML in the loadString:baseURL: method.

Any ideas what might be going on?

Thanks for any help!
Rob

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is trying to load the HTML synchronously so the network latency on the device might have been long enough to hang the thread. By the way you might wanna tag this question with iphone so people would know you are talking about Objective-C iPhone SDK

Comment: The network latency shouldn't be an issue. I watch the URL requests coming from the HTML and then open a modal view. This is not happening on the device as it did in the simulator. Also thanks for the tag reminder, it never serves to get into too much of a hurry.